Could someone explain simply the syntax related to summing over axes in a Numpy meshgrid to reduce dimension?
I want to generate a function that acts on five 1D arrays and returns a 5D array. Then I want to "sum over" three of the axes of the function to reduce it to a 2D array which is then plotted on a pcolormesh against the two axes that were not summed over. I thought I understood how to do this, but apparently I am missing something and I haven't found a good explanation of what I'm getting wrong.
Here is the outline of what I've tried:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.linspace(-10, 10)
b = np.linspace(-10, 10)
c = np.linspace(-10, 10)
d = np.linspace(-5, 5)
e = np.linspace(-7, 7)

A, B, C = np.meshgrid(a,b,c)

D, E = np.meshgrid(d, e)

def f(a,b,c,d,e):
    return a**2  + b**3 + c**6 + d + 2*e**3

F = np.sum(f(A, B, C, D, E), axis = 0) 
G = np.sum(F, axis = (2,3)) 

plt.pcolormesh(B, C, G)
plt.show()

My understanding was that the line F = np.sum(f(A, B, C, D, E), axis = 0) would sum the function over all values of a within the corresponding linspace and therefore return f evaluated on the remaining 4 axes B, C, D, E and then subsequently the line G = np.sum(K, axis = 2,3)  would sum over D,E to return a 2D array of f evaluated on the B, C axes and summed over the rest (in the minimal example here, I could fold the lines for producing F and G together, but in my real code the total array is too big for memory, so I'm splitting it up).
Can someone please explain to me in laymen's terms what is going wrong and the correct syntax for producing the desired result?

What is going wrong in your current code is that with splitting the meshgrid creation between a,b,c and d,e, you will never generate a 5D intermediate result in calling f():

Calling A, B, C = np.meshgrid(a, b, c) will create 3 n×n×n (thus three 3D) arrays.

Calling D, E = np.meshgrid(d, e) will create 2 n×n (thus two 2D) arrays.

Calling f() with the mix of 2D and 3D arrays will trigger "broadcasting", i.e. it will

align the elements of all arrays in the last two axes (which is possible because the shape in the last two axes is n×n for all arrays) and
repeat the 2D arrays as often as necessary along the remaining axis (i.e. n times along the first axis of the 3D arrays).

Thus, you will mix up dimensions which you actually want to keep separate (if I understand your question correctly), and you will end up with a 3D array as the result of calling f() rather than the expected 5D array.


The last point is essential: NumPy cannot know that the dimensions of a,b,c and d,e should be kept separate. Based on the shapes of the arrays, NumPy generally will apply broadcasting rules in calculations whenever it seems necessary and is possible (which is the case with your data, see above) and will raise an error if array shapes are incompatible with each other in a broadcasting sense. For more detail on NumPy's broadcasting rules, see e.g. here.
What you would need instead, is A, B, C, D, E = np.meshgrid(a, b, c, d, e), to create five 5D arrays that keep different dimensions apart in the f() calculation.
Avoid np.meshgrid()
However, if I understand your question correctly, you would actually not need to use np.meshgrid() in the first place. What works just as well, is aligning a, b, c, d, e along five different axes (i.e. making a an n×1×1×1×1 array, making b a 1×n×1×1×1 array, etc.). Then their summation in f() will broadcast the values automatically.
In fact, you will save memory this way: with the default value of n=50 samples per linspace() call, your result of calling f() would already hold 50⁵ float values, thus 8·50⁵B=2.5GB. With creating a meshgrid from a, b, c, d, e, you would use up another 5·2.5GB=12.5GB unnecessarily.
The code below should produce the desired result:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_samples = 50

a = np.linspace(-10, 10, num_samples)
b = np.linspace(-10, 10, num_samples)
c = np.linspace(-10, 10, num_samples)
d = np.linspace(-5, 5, num_samples)
e = np.linspace(-7, 7, num_samples)

def g(a, b, c, d, e):
    # Align a, b, c, d, e along 5 different axes
    A = a.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1, 1)  # num_samples × 1 × 1 × 1 × 1
    B = b.reshape(1, -1, 1, 1, 1)  # .
    C = c.reshape(1, 1, -1, 1, 1)  # .
    D = d.reshape(1, 1, 1, -1, 1)  # .
    E = e.reshape(1, 1, 1, 1, -1)  # 1 × 1 × 1 × 1 × num_samples
    
    def f(a, b, c, d, e):
        return a ** 2 + b ** 3 + c ** 6 + d + 2 * e ** 3
    
    F = np.sum(f(A, B, C, D, E), axis = 0) 
    G = np.sum(F, axis = (2,3)) 
    return G

plt.pcolormesh(c, b, g(a, b, c, d, e))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

Avoid explicitly calculating the 5D array altogether
Finally, I don't know what your function f() looks like in reality, but maybe you could even get away without calculating the n×n×n×n×n intermediate result of calling f().
With the function f() and summation that you give in the question, the following should produce exactly the same result:
def g_proposed(a, b, c, d, e):
    la, ld, le = len(a), len(d), len(e)
    A = (a ** 2).sum()
    B = (b ** 3).reshape(-1, 1)
    C = (c ** 6).reshape(1, -1)
    D = d.sum()
    E = 2 * (e ** 3).sum()
    G = ld*le * A + la*ld*le * (B + C)  + la*le * D + la*ld * E
    return G
    
assert np.allclose(g(a, b, c, d, e), g_proposed(a, b, c, d, e)) 

Or, maybe a bit clearer:
def g_proposed(a, b, c, d, e):
    la, ld, le = len(a), len(d), len(e)
    A = (1 / la) * (a ** 2).sum()  # Or simply: (a ** 2).mean()
    B = (b ** 3).reshape(-1, 1)
    C = (c ** 6).reshape(1, -1)
    D = (1 / ld) * d.sum()
    E = (1 / le) * 2 * (e ** 3).sum()
    G = la*ld*le * (A + B + C + D + E)
    return G
    
assert np.allclose(g(a, b, c, d, e), g_proposed(a, b, c, d, e)) 

In either version, g_proposed() would be way more memory-and-time efficient, as we never create the 5D intermediate array explicitly. Instead, we can work with data of a maximum of two dimensions (namely, the axes that we do not want to reduce over). On my machine, I can happily use g_proposed() with num_samples = 1000, while it already folds using g() with num_samples = 100.
What we do here:

We raise each variable to its appropriate power.
We directly sum over the variables that we want to sum over.
We compensate for the direct summation by multiplying the other variables with the respective lengths.

The following example maybe demonstrates how/why this works:
   ┌ a, a ┐   ┌ d, e ┐
  (| b, b | + | d, e |).sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
   └ c, c ┘   └ d, e ┘

  ┌ a+d, a+e ┐
= | b+d, b+e |.sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
  └ c+d, c+e ┘

= [a+b+c+3d, a+b+c+3e].sum()

= 2a+2b+2d+3d+3e

= 2*(a+b+c) + 3*(d+e)

= len([d,e])*[a,b,c].sum() + len([a,b,c])*[d,e].sum()


This really helped, thanks!
As to your point about avoiding the 5D array: the actual function has the form f(a,b,c,d,e) = F_1(a, d) * G_1(a, e) * F_2(b, d) * G_2(b, e) * F_3(c, d) * G_3(c, e)
Where F_{1,2,3} and G_{1,2,3} are completely unseparable functions. So there's probably room for some cleaning up but not quite in exactly the way you said.
Do you see a quick way of translating your more efficient code to work with the new minimal example?

@CodyPayne Is the result of F_1, F_2, F_3, G_1, G_2, G_3 one-dimensional each (i.e. you multiply them relying on broadcasting) or is each output multidimensional?

Oh yeah, important clarification. F_1(a,d) = np.exp(-a**2) * np.exp(1j * a * d) with a similar form for all the other functions, so they are 1D arrays that rely on broadcasting.

@CodyPayne Thanks for the clarification. I need to think about this when I have time. I guess a similar trick should be possible, given that (1) all functions are multiplied in the end and (2) the log of a product is the same as the sum of the logs (so maybe one would need to move to log space). As I said, I would need to think this through. But maybe you can.

Thank you again. I'll think about it too and get back to you if I figure out a good strategy.

@CodyPayne I thought about it and I did not find a similar possibility to avoid the 5D intermediate result. Problem indeed is that F_*, G_* are multiplied. So even if we calculated log(F_1) + log(G_1) + …, instead, we would need to surround everything with exp() before reducing (i.e. applying sum()). The exp(), however, prevents us from summing the individual axes. So I am afraid, I think you have to live with the 5D intermediate result. But you still should get away without the meshgrid().

Whats the etiquette to exchange code here? Edit the original post or make a new answer? I think I see a way of separating it out that I'd like you to take a look at and also have for posterity to help people in the future.

I am not sure. If it totally alters the meaning of the question, I would probably post a new question. If it adds more detail, I would probably add an "Update" section to the question. I guess there are many cases that lie on a middle ground.

Nevermind. After I actually got to write it out I realize that you're absolutely right.
